# Object handles in javascript

Tags: javascript, graphics

Is there some javascript alternative or solution like this: www.objecthandles.com
I'm making a web-based diagram-like program, where you can add basic shapes that need to be able to be moved, resized, and rotated.

Comment: i am betting on a canvas HTML5 solution perhaps.

Comment: Is there a canvas library that has object handles or something of the like?

Comment: i know a couple http://jcscript.com/ and http://guryjs.org/ but never used them myself

Comment: I'll actually probably use http://raphaeljs.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, maybe this will work? http://www.jointjs.com/

Comment: That's pretty cool, but i need the resize/rotate handles like objecthandles.com

Comment: It'll require tweaking, but it's pretty sweet.